# Python3 reimporting __builtins__

Tags: python-3.x

Assume I delete all my builtins using `__builtins__={}` Is there a way to force the reimport of all base modules? I thought about using `_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter`, could that be done using that method?

The goal is to see whether it can be done and how to extricate yourself from such a situation. It has no use beyond simply learning esoteric parts of python. This is python3 btw.

Comment: Doing `__builtins__ = {}` doesn't delete them, Try calling a builtin like `max` and you can see they can be called

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh `__builtins__ = {}` does delete them and can't be used in the current script, try it.

Comment: Doing `__builtins__ = {}; print(max([1,2,3]))` gives me `3`, and I assume `max` is a buitlin, or am I missing something

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Which Python version are you running? I'm running 3.5.0 and they're getting deleted.

Comment: I am running `3.7`

Comment: Maybe the two of you are using different environments. If I do `__builtins__ = {}` in a script, I can continue to access my builtins. If I do `__builtins__ = {}` in a REPL, I can no longer access my builtins. I'm using 3.7.3 for both.

Comment: @Kevin You're right, I tested on a script and it's working, but using the REPL can't access them.

Comment: I’m 100% sure that in my script I can’t use it. I get an undefined error when using ‚open‘ for instance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @Kevin noted in the comments, this seems to be different between the REPL and a script. In a script, reassigning `__builtins__` seems to have no effect (Python 3.7.3):

```
# test.py
__builtins__ = {}

print(max([1,2,3]))

def really_weird():
    __builtins__ = {"max": lambda x: min(x)}
    print(max([1,2,3]))

really_weird()


# Output
3
3
```

`max` didn't change, even when `__builtins__` reassigned the name (sort of).

In the REPL, you are correct that `_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter` can be used.

```
>>> import _frozen_importlib   # This must be before reassigning __builtins___, since __builtins__ includes __import__
>>> __builtins__ = {}
>>> max([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'max' is not defined
>>> __builtins__ = _frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter().load_module("builtins")
>>> max([1,2,3])
3
```

One thing to note: The module name is `builtins`, not `__builtins__`.

Also, as is noted in the comments, doing `import builtins as b; ... __builtins__ = b` or something similar also works.

If you don't want to do setup work, @Kevin's answer does the same without previous imports.

Comment: while all answers are great, this uses my first hunch and thus solves the problem in a satisfactory way :)

Comment: This is a pretty bogus solution.  If using `import _frozen_importlib` *before* clearing builtins is counting as "solving the problem", then why not just `import builtins as othername` and cut out the middleman?

Comment: actually good point. What I actually used was: ```__builtins__ = [].class.mro[1].subclasses()[80].load_module('builtins')```since obviously ```import``` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

One highly impractical method of accessing the builtins module when its name is inaccessible is described at the bottom of https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html.

> Update: from a [thread on Reddit about recovering cleared globals](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/hftnp/ask_rpython_recovering_cleared_globals/), a similar snippet that will get you the original builtins:
>
> ```
> [
>     c for c in ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__() 
>     if c.__name__ == 'catch_warnings'
> ][0]()._module.__builtins__
> ```

By reassigning this object to `__builtins__`, the built-in objects become accessible again.

```
>>> __builtins__ = {}
>>> max
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'max' is not defined
>>> __builtins__ = [c for c in ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__() if c.__name__ == 'catch_warnings'][0]()._module.__builtins__
>>> max
<built-in function max>
```

Quick explanation of the components of the statement:

```
                           () #tuple instance
                           ().__class__ #the tuple class
                           ().__class__.__base__ #tuple's base class, i.e. `object`
                           ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__() #every class that inherits from `object`
               [c for c in ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__() if c.__name__ == 'catch_warnings'][0] #the `warnings.catch_warnings` class
               [c for c in ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__() if c.__name__ == 'catch_warnings'][0]()._module #create a `catch_warnings` instance and access its `_module` attribute, which is the `warnings` module.
               [c for c in ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__() if c.__name__ == 'catch_warnings'][0]()._module.__builtins__ #`warnings.__builtins__` is the builtins module
__builtins__ = [c for c in ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__() if c.__name__ == 'catch_warnings'][0]()._module.__builtins__ #assign result to `__builtins__`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question was [proposed as a puzzle in the Python chat room, back in March 2018](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41443342#41443342).

The following solution, given by user [Aran-Fey](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41443504#41443504), restores the builtins module afresh in the REPL:

```
__builtins__ = __loader__.create_module(__loader__.find_spec('builtins'))
```

A more difficult variant, additionally clearing the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) namespace and thus denying access to [`__loader__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__loader__), was also [proposed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41444184#41444184) ([and solved](https://sopython.com/spoiler/ICAgIHR5cGUgPSAnJy5fX2NsYXNzX18uX19jbGFzc19fDQogICAgQUJDTWV0YSA9IHR5cGUuX19zdWJjbGFzc2VzX18odHlwZSlbMF0NCiAgICBhYmNfZ2xvYmFscyA9IEFCQ01ldGEucmVnaXN0ZXIuX19nbG9iYWxzX18NCiAgICBpbXBvcnRsaWJfZ2xvYmFscyA9IGFiY19nbG9iYWxzWydfX2xvYWRlcl9fJ10uZ2V0X2RhdGEuX19nbG9iYWxzX18NCiAgICBfX2J1aWx0aW5zX18gPSBpbXBvcnRsaWJfZ2xvYmFsc1snc3lzJ10ubW9kdWxlc1snYnVpbHRpbnMnXQ0KICAgIF9fYnVpbHRpbnNfXy5fX3NwZWNfXy5sb2FkZXIuY3JlYXRlX21vZHVsZShfX2J1aWx0aW5zX18uX19zcGVjX18p)) in the chat room.

*Note that setting `__builtins__ = {}` only disables access to the builtin namespace within an interactive REPL, not within a script, and the lookup in `__builtins__` is considered [a CPython implementation detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html).*